# colorbox - enable clicks outside of it

Tags: jquery-plugins, colorbox

I'm using colorbox, and I want to be able to click on the webpage behind the colorbox while it is open.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of lightbox-like "windows" is that they shadow the website while they are open.

But you can add the following to your CSS to hide the overlay:

```
#cboxOverlay { display: none !important; }
```

This will allow you to click on the site even with the colorbox being shown.

Comment: I second that +1 / accept.  We only do this because we are point addicts.  But I would recommend adding an `onLoad: function() { $('#cboxOverlay').hide(); }` option rather than doing it in CSS so that it only applies to the colorbox instance that should have this functionality.

Comment: If he wants it only for certain boxes then yes - if he wants it globally, the CSS way is better.